# Conflict between inHouse & appStore distribution profiles

Tags: ios, app-store, distribution

We have a distribution profile for appStore releases & one for inHouse distribution. Both have identical Company names. The problem we encounter now is that when we try and build for distribution, we get the error:

```
[BEROR]CodeSign error: Certificate identity 'iPhone Distribution: OurCompanyName' appears more than once in the keychain. The codesign tool requires there only be one.
```

How do we fix this?

Edit: The mac we're using to sign is used for continuous integration (via Bamboo), so it's meant to build unattended.
This makes switching user accounts an impossibility...

Comment: Either the suggestion from hotpaw2... or remove one of them temporarily whilst you complete the distribution build?

Comment: Yep, that's the way we create distributions for the app store now. This workaround will do for now, But we really need a fix.

Comment: Received a tip from Apple to rename a certificate. Have not had a chance yet to try this out. Stay tuned...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solution:
I've put all the appstore related stuff in the login keychain, and the enterprise stuff in a seperate keychain file.

In the buildscript, I switch between those as follows:

```
    # 1. Only activate the System and either the Appstore(=login) or Enterprise keychain.
security list-keychains -s $KEYCHAIN_NAME $SYSTEM_KEYCHAIN

# 2. Loop through App Schema's
for APP_SCHEME in ${APP_SCHEMES[@]}; do
    echo "--=  Processing $APP_SCHEME  =--"
    xcodebuild -scheme "${APP_SCHEME}" archive
done ### Looping through App Schema's

# 3. Restore login & system keychains
security list-keychains -s $APPSTORE_KEYCHAIN $ENTERPRISE_KEYCHAIN $SYSTEM_KEYCHAIN
```

Answer (score 0):

Use two different Mac User accounts (different logins) to hold the two different sets of Certificates and provisions (two different keychains, etc.).  Check the source code out from a shared repository, and do the final builds in the appropriate User accounts.

Comment: That would be a fix for manual building. But since we are trying to achieve continuous integration I would need a better fix.
In the meanwhile, we've asked Apple to change our name for the enterprise account.....

Comment: OSX is multiuser.  You should be able to run codesign servers in both accounts.